# DeviceIoControl in C# results in 998 error: Invalid access to memory location

Tags: c#, driver

I have a simple C driver that accepts a ULONG parameter. In C language I use:

```
   unsigned long ip = atoll(argv[1]);
   if (!DeviceIoControl(
        DeviceHandle,
        0x10,
        &ip,
        sizeof(ip),
        NULL,
        0,
        &BytesReturned,
        NULL
    ))
```

It works well, but when I do it in C#,

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DeviceIoControl([In] IntPtr hDevice,
    [In] int dwIoControlCode, [In] IntPtr lpInBuffer,
    [In] int nInBufferSize, [Out] IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
    [In] int nOutBufferSize, out int lpBytesReturned,
    [In] IntPtr lpOverlapped);

...

Int64 ip = ip2long(ipstr);
if (! Win32.DeviceIoControl(
   hDevice, 0x10, 
   (IntPtr) ip, Marshal.SizeOf(ip), 
   IntPtr.Zero, 0, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
{
   throw new Exception("DeviceIoControl(): " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

It always result in 998 error: Invalid memory access.

From DbgView, the call never reached the driver. What was wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, you can't convert uint to IntPtr directly. You must allocate memory to do that:

```
IntPtr ipPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ip));
Marshal.WriteInt64(ipPtr, ip);
```